# Need help unlocking a question

Tags: support

I feel like my question is locked by a moderator without cause (anymore).

[What's the equivalent of Nagios time periods in Prometheus?](https://serverfault.com/questions/992620/whats-the-equivalent-of-nagios-time-periods-in-prometheus?noredirect=1#comment1291825_992620)

Can someone step in here?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment there, it would make it clearer if you would define the time period you're actually interested in and ask how to configure that in Prometheus.  I think that's what you mean, but since your example Nagios time period is "all the time," I'm not sure.

Comment: Is that usually enough reason to put question on hold? I've been here long enough to have seen way worse things and I always try to help. Looks like I got caught by an angry moderator this time.

Comment: @GiovanniTirloni I don't see an angry moderator. I would have done the same thing. A time period covering every possible minute of the week is senseless.

Comment: I wasn't angry before, but when I reviewed the tracking bug for the feature I found that the OP had already found it and commented on it, but hadn't bothered to mention this in the question.

Comment: And you again locked the question, care to explain why?

Comment: The close reason gives sufficient information.